# 600 ohm modem transformer impedance calculation by formula

Tags: transformer, telephone

From the datasheet of a [modem transformer](http://www.datatronics.com/pdf/pt79546.pdf)
we have:

- Impedance, Primary:   600 Ω Typ. @ 1 kHz 1 Vrms*
- Shunt Inductance Lp, Primary: 3.2 H min. @ 1 kHz
- D.C. resistance @20°C: Primary = 82 Ω ± 15%

Also the impedance formula:

$$ Z= \sqrt{R^2+(XL-XC)^2} $$

How does 600 Ω result from 3.2 H and 82 Ω? 
(The X<sub>C</sub> is negligible.)

Comment: You will get your 600Ω only if the load the Secondary with a 420Ω resistor.  Look at the asterisk note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does 600 Ω result from 3.2 H and 82 Ω? (The XC is negligible.)

Think about what the spec says and read this below.

[image]